# How to animate the text in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a sidebar animation effect as:

```
<div class="sidebar-description sidebar-personal-info-section">
    A passionate
    <span class="changing-keywords" id="change">
        <strong>
            <b class="hidden">software engineer</b>
            <b class="hidden">lifelong learner</b>
            <b class="hidden">blogger</b>
            <b class="hidden">traveller</b>
        </strong>
    </span><br>
</div>
```

I've written the HTML code but issue is that how should I display each text one at a time with small delay with `slide-out` animation effect? The loop should work infinite times.

Comment: How should I proceed? It would be a great help :) Thanks!

Comment: might be a job for setInterval and use a counter or rotate your array of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it simple by using CSS key-frame animation.

Below is an example.

```css
body{
    font-family:calibri;
  }
.codinfox-changing-keywords{
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:20px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
}
.hidden{
  position:absolute;
  top: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
    opacity:0;
  animation: slideme 8s infinite;
}
.hidden:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.hidden:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.hidden:nth-child(7){
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes slideme {
  0% {
    top: 20px;
    opacity:0;
  }
  5% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  10%{
    top : 0;
    opacity:1;
  }
  20%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {    
  opacity:0.1;
    top : 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity:0;
    top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="codinfox-sidebar-description sidebar-personal-info-section">
    A passionate
    <div class="codinfox-changing-keywords" id="change">
        <strong>
            <b class="hidden">software engineer</b><br/>
            <b class="hidden">lifelong learner</b><br/>
            <b class="hidden">blogger</b><br/>
            <b class="hidden">traveller</b>
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/Lc3mk806/) as well!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to work a little bit on your HTML. The `<strong>` tag shouldn't be used to style elements, not to mention the `<b>` tags. Below is my version of the code. First the HTML:

```
<div class="codinfox-sidebar-description sidebar-personal-info-section">
    A passionate
    <span class="changing-keyword shown">software engineer</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">lifelong learner</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">blogger</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">traveller</span>
</div>
```

I took the liberity to change the class names and remove some tags that were, in my opinion, unnecessary here. Now, JavaScript:

```
const changingKeywords = document.querySelectorAll('span.changing-keyword');
const keywordsToggle = setKeywordsToggle(changingKeywords);

function setKeywordsToggle (keywords) {
    let index = 0;
  return setInterval(() => {
    keywords[index].classList.remove('shown');
    if (++index >= keywords.length) 
        index = 0;
    keywords[index].classList.add('shown');
  }, 2000);
}
```

Notice that I actually **return** the **setInterval()** function and assign it to **keywordsToggle** variable. This way, if I ever want to stop the animation, I can easily do so by running **clearInterval()**. The code toggles through all keywords it finds and assigns the **shown** class to the element determined by the value of **index** variable.

Finally, sample CSS:

```
.sidebar-personal-info-section {
  position: relative;
}

.changing-keyword {
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
  visibility: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: .2rem;
}

.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Notice the **visibility** transition, which actually works as transition delay. Other than that, I had to use a **position** property to make sure that every keyword is positioned near the "passionate" word, otherwise every word would appear in it's original position (I didn't use **display:none** since it's not animatable).

Working example:

```js
const changingKeywords = document.querySelectorAll('span.changing-keyword');
const keywordsToggle = setKeywordsToggle(changingKeywords);

function setKeywordsToggle (keywords) {
 let index = 0;
  return setInterval(() => {
   keywords[index].classList.remove('shown');
    if (++index >= keywords.length) 
     index = 0;
    keywords[index].classList.add('shown');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.sidebar-personal-info-section {
  position: relative;
}

.changing-keyword {
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
  visibility: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: .2rem;
}

.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="codinfox-sidebar-description sidebar-personal-info-section">
    A passionate
    <span class="changing-keyword shown">software engineer</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">lifelong learner</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">blogger</span>
    <span class="changing-keyword">traveller</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty would look something like this.

```
// add rotate to Array
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n) {
    return this.slice(n, this.length).concat(this.slice(0, n));
}

// setup array
const jobs = ['employee', 'manager'];

// rotate jobs function
const rotateJobs = () => {
    document.querySelector('#id').innerHtml = jobs.rotate(1).shift();
}

// set interval
setInterval(rotateJobs, 1000);
```

The fade in / slide animation should be handled in css transitions.

Comment: Have you actually run this code? `rotate` produces a new array so `rotateJobs` will always yield the same result. In any case this is a lot of extra work to avoid iterating through the array of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

This something what I finally figured out!

```
var title = ['software engineer', 'tech blogger', 'traveller', 'lifelong learner'];

var i = 0;  // the index of the current item to show

setInterval(function() {            // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
  document
    .getElementById('change')
    .innerHTML = title[i++];    // get the item and increment
  if (i == title.length) i = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 2000);
```