# Is this rotating text effect effect possible using CSS alone?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I came across an animation, which I think could be useful on one of my sites. I saw it on the blogging platform overblog, specifically on this page: **https://en.over-blog.com/signup**.

The animation I'm referring to rotates through a number of words (or small phrases) one after another, before resetting back to the beginning once all phrases had been cycled through.

I'm not fantastic with CSS, so wondered if this was possibly done using just CSS or whether it needed the assistance of javascript.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It can be done just with CSS. In fact, your example is done with just CSS. I'll try to make some code to answer in a bit

Comment: looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881172/how-to-animate-the-text-in-a-for-loop/52882423#52882423) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897158/having-trouble-with-sliding-word-animation/57912541#57912541)?

Answer (score -1):

OK... I've made an example for you

The basics are simple. You have a fixed sentence and after it, you have a column with diferent texts. The column have a fixed height with `overflow:hidden;` so you can just see the first word os the list.

Then you create an animation to move the words upwards with `translate3d` property.

It's easy but it will take you some time to find the right percent of translation to stop the word a bit in the right position.

to start:

```
0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
```

And the I found the right percent to end the animation is (more or less):

```
95%,100% { transform: translate3D(0, -960%, 0);}
```

I have used `95%,100%` so the word stop for a while before starting again

And as last example, I've used:

```
35%, 40% { transform: translate3d(0, -320%, 0);}
```

where `-320%` is (again more or less) third word position.

Here you have:

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
}
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
  margin:0; padding:0;
  }
ul li {
  margin-bottom:30px;
  }
.animation {
  display:block;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite ;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes animation {
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);} 
  35%, 40% { transform: translate3d(0, -320%, 0);} 
   85%,90% { transform: translate3D(0, -960%, 0);}
  95%, 100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);} 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is a sentence</span>
  <div class="column" style="color:red;">
    <ul>
      <li class="animation" style="color:red;">one</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:blue;">two</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:green;">three</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:red;">four</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:blue;">five</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:green;">six</li>
      <li class="animation" style="color:red;">seven</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Find the right spots to stop every word.

**Edited:** I have change a bit the `snippet` to make the words return to origin as in your example